# Error in user.id while saving data in Model - Commit False not working

Tags: django, django-models

I am using `AbstractBaseUser` for that i have created a `managers.py` for creating `superuser`.

Everything is working except these line in managers.py. Even i tried to `print(user.id)` before `user.save(using=self._db)` it is printing `None`

```
user.save(using=self._db)
user.created_by_id = user.id
user.updated_by_id = user.id
user.save()
```

I have also used `commit=False` in `user.save(using=self._db, commit=False)` still it is giving error. See the errors at bottom.

In my models.py i have tweo field `created_by` & `updated_by` which should should not be null. Thats why i am saving in Managers.py which is creating all this error.

How can i solve this issue. Is there better approach. This condition is only required for creating superuser.

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('is user active'), default=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='user-avatar.png', upload_to='users/', null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=True)

    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='user_created_by')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('user created on'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='user_updated_by')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_('user updated on'), auto_now=True)
```

Managers.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.role_id = 1
        user.first_name = "Super"
        user.last_name = "Admin"
        user.save(using=self._db)
        user.created_by_id = user.id
        user.updated_by_id = user.id
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Error - for `commit=False`

```
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'
```

Error - Without Commit False

```
raise utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'created_by_id' cannot be null")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commit=False` works for [ModelForms](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L441). It does not work for model instances. As the error said in your question, there is no keyword argument named `commit` exists in [save](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L663) method.

Also, before saving the user object, it can't produce any primary key. I would recommend to make `created_by` null able. So that you can avoid integrity error.

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='user_created_by', null=True, default=None)

updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='user_updated_by', null=True, default=None)
```

Still, if you want to enforce this restriction, then you can do that in forms or serializer or override the save method as well in the `User` model.

For example:

```
class User(...):
   ...
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.is_superuser:
          if not self.created_by or not self.updated_by:
               raise Exception("Add these fields")  # can be custom exception

       super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: previously i kept it `null=True`. But due to some issue that i was going to face in future, i kept it as `null=False`. Is there any different approach